# Package name does not correspond to the file path- Android studio error after changing package name

Tags: android

I changed the package name from **ielts_training_serv02.migrationpackage** to **ielts_training_serv02.alan.migrationpackage**. I did this by changing package name in the manifest and the application Id in build.gradle. I also created a new package "alan" inside "ielts_training_serv02" and moved package "migrationpackage" to "alan".

After doing this, I'm getting the following error:[image: error1]

and this error:
[image]

Comment: Try to revert your changes and do a refactoring via your Android Studio IDE by right clicking on the package and chose Refactor > Rename. This should avoid such problems.

Comment: @DavidArtmann I cant revert it back. I want my package name to be ielts_training_serv02.alan.migrationpackage. Basically what Im trying to do is change package name from a.c to a.b.c. But my approach is wrong i guess

Comment: You can do the change manually of course, but this would require you to alter every package name in every class inside of the edited package (like the one in your screenshot).